# Title where CheckBox Preference is Check or not

Tags: java, android, xml, android-checkbox

I have a settings menu where I have a `CheckBox Preference`. I wish that when the `CheckBox` is checked, displays an android: Title and when it is it shows another.

This is what I've done so far

**Settings.xml**

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="no_notification"
    android:summary="Disable Notification message"
    android:title="@string/titolo"
    android:summaryOn="@string/acceso"
    android:summaryOff="@string/spento"
    />
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<string name="titolo">Disable / Enable Notification</string>
<string name="acceso">Enable notification</string>
<string name="spento">Disable Notification</string>
```

In practice, I would like that when it is not Checked shows how Android:title Disable and when it Checked Enable. How can I do?

Comment: you can create Object of CheckBoxPreference and then chack it.      `final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("no_notification");`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html       isChecked()  Returns the checked state. THIS MAY HELP U ...

Comment: Yes, but how do I tell him to change the android: title?

Comment: i think `CheckBoxPreference` have setTitle(int) method ! i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> On listerner r you can add :

```
checkBoxcmp.setEnabled(true);
```